# Troubles Submitting Form programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple page that takes a `form` and makes a `jsonp` `ajax` request and formats the response and displays it on the page, this is all fine, but I wanted to add it so that if the form was populated (via php `$_GET` variables) then the form would auto-submit on page load but what happens instead is that the page constantly refreshes despite the `submit` function returning `false`.

**Submit Button (just to show it doesn't have an `id` like `submit` or anything)**

```
<button type="submit" id="check" class="btn btn-success">Check</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_form').on('submit', function() {

        var valid = 1;

        $('#my_form .required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                valid = 0;
            } else {
                $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });

        if (valid === 1) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/some_url',
                data: $('#my_form').serialize(),
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {

                    var html = 'do something with data';

                    $('#results').html(html);

                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#results').html('An error occurred, please try again');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#results').html('Please fill in all required fields');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

The part I added just after the `$(document).ready(function(){` and before the `submit` was:

```
if ($('#input_1').val() != '' || $('#input_2').val() != '') {
    // $('#check').trigger('click');
    $('#my_form').submit();
}
```

Both those lines have the same effect but I am doing the same in another project and it works fine, as far as I can see, the only difference is the jQuery version, I'm using `1.11` for this page.

**Update**

Apologies, I seem to have answered my own question, I thought that since the programmatic `submit` was the first thing in `$(document).ready(function(){` then maybe it was the case that the actual `submit` function wasn't being reached before the event was triggered so I simply moved that block after the `submit`function and it now works fine.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719609/prevent-default-form-submit-when-submitting-from-javascript

Comment: @hindmost, very similar but that question isn't very helpful but nevermind, I have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: ''
```

it seems like you are sending your ajax request to nothing.

just an additional: if you want to submit your form through jquery without using AJAX, try

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```

it will send your form to the action attribute of the form, then redirect the page there.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the confusion about the `url`, I just left it blank as it's pointing to an internal api, I will update the question with some placeholder  instead. I managed to find the issue with the submit aswell.